# Sync Stylish styles across Chrome and Firefox

Tags: browser, css, styles

Is there a way I can set the path of the Stylish addon for `.sqlite` file for Firefox and Chrome to the same location? In Firefox I know it's in the `extensions.stylish.dbFile` config, but I have no idea where it is in Chrome. My goal is to use the same styles for both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/31737/sync-stylish-styles-across-chrome-and-firefox) it is not possible.

> http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/31168/where-are-user-styles-stored-on-chrome
>
> A hard link would do the trick, but the databases have different structures in Firefox and Chrome, so it will do you no good.

Answer (score -1):

### For Google chrome/Vivaldi/Chromium-based browsers

- the file you need to back up it located at `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/XXXXXX/IndexDB/chrome-extension_fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe_0.indexeddb.leveldb/000003.log`

  - for Google Chrome, `XXXXXX` is **Google/Chrome**
  - for Vivaldi, `XXXXXX` is **Vivaldi**
- by studying the extension code, `Extensions/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe/1.5.2_0/storage-websql.js` has a property `getDatabase` which defines the database used for styles storage.
- the database is located at `databases/chrome-extension_fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe_0/[0-9]+`, but the SQLite DB file contains a table, `__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__`, which has a field `WebKitDatabaseVersionKey` which is null. This means the bd file is useless and the data is not stored in it.

### how to backup and restore

- you can write a shell script to automatically do this for you daily or weekly.
- just zip the `chrome-extension_fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe_0.indexeddb.leveldb` folder using `7z` or `tar` and copy the zip file to icloud or dropbox.

check [here](https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/31168/where-are-user-styles-stored-on-chrome#latest), I have comments in this topic.

### For firefox

- I actually use the  `userContent.css`, which is located at `/Users/ruili/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/wbcdxsme.default/chrome/userContent.css`. [if not existed, just create it]
- the syntax is specified [here](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites)

`CSS
@-moz-document domain(www.hao123.com) {
}
@-moz-document url(http://www.example.com/test.html) {
}
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://www.example.com"){
}
@-moz-document regexp('http://www\\.example\\.(com|de)/images/.*') {
}`